# HTML Responsive Design - Scaling to various display resolutions

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, responsive-design

I'm fairly novice with front-end web design and have been struggling with making the following webpage have a more responsive design:

[The webpage made with Ionic Framework displayed on a 1920x1080 monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgDbg.png)

I am fairly happy with the sizing, layout and ratios as is; however, the webpage still does not scale very well to other screen resolutions. I try to use % based sizing wherever possible but many elements still do not scale nicely.

[The webpage displayed on lower resolution monitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46VP8.png)

Buttons get clipped, the size ratio of elements to their parent blocks gets messed up, text remains the same size, block #1 items overlaps the rest of the card. I would like guidance on how to best approach making the webpage as consistent as possible across various resolutions or general suggestions you might have on improving my responsive design.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=0.01, user-scalable=1.0" />
<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark" />
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />

<ion-app style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <ion-content style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <ion-grid style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <ion-row style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                <ion-col id="grid_left_half" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; background-color: #5E5694;" class="col_vertical_align">
                    <ion-row id="col_upper_half" style="width: 85%; height: 50%; background-color: #3B666B;">
                        <ion-col id="block_one" style="height: 100%; width: 50%;">
                            <ion-card style="height: 95%;">
                                <ion-card-header style="height: 10%;">
                                    <ion-card-title>Block #1</ion-card-title>
                                </ion-card-header>
                                <ion-card-content style="height: 65%;">
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Variable #1</ion-label>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Variable #2</ion-label>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Variable #3</ion-label>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Variable #4</ion-label>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Variable #5</ion-label>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Variable #6</ion-label>
                                    </ion-item>
                                </ion-card-content>`
                                <ion-card-content class="stretch_content_horizontally">
                                    <form id="form_one" action="/" method="get">
                                        <ion-button id="button_one" type="submit" disabled>
                                            aaaaaa
                                        </ion-button>
                                    </form>
                                    <form id="form_two" action="/" method="get">
                                        <ion-button id="button_two" type="submit" disabled>
                                            bbbbbb
                                        </ion-button>
                                    </form>
                                    <ion-button id="button_three" type="submit" onclick="">
                                        ccccccc
                                    </ion-button>
                                </ion-card-content>
                            </ion-card>
                        </ion-col>

                        <ion-col id="block_two" style="height: 100%; width: 50%;">
                            <ion-card style="height: 95%;">
                                <ion-card-header>
                                    <ion-card-title>
                                        Block #2
                                    </ion-card-title>
                                </ion-card-header>
                                <ion-card-content style="height: 65%; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">
                                    <ion-list id="block_two_list" style="height: 100%;">
                                        <ion-item>
                                            <ion-label>
                                                Entry #1
                                            </ion-label>
                                            <ion-button style="float: right;">
                                                mmmm
                                            </ion-button>
                                        </ion-item>
                                        <ion-item>
                                            <ion-label>
                                                Entry #2
                                            </ion-label>
                                            <ion-button style="float: right;">
                                                mmmm
                                            </ion-button>
                                        </ion-item>
                                        <ion-item>
                                            <ion-label>
                                                Entry #3
                                            </ion-label>
                                            <ion-button style="float: right;">
                                                mmmm
                                            </ion-button>
                                        </ion-item>
                                        <ion-item>
                                            <ion-label>
                                                Entry #4
                                            </ion-label>
                                            <ion-button style="float: right;">
                                                mmmm
                                            </ion-button>
                                        </ion-item>
                                        <ion-item>
                                            <ion-label>
                                                Entry #5
                                            </ion-label>
                                            <ion-button style="float: right;">
                                                mmmm
                                            </ion-button>
                                        </ion-item>
                                        <ion-item>
                                            <ion-label>
                                                Entry #6
                                            </ion-label>
                                            <ion-button style="float: right;">
                                                mmmm
                                            </ion-button>
                                        </ion-item>
                                        <ion-item>
                                            <ion-label>
                                                Entry #7
                                            </ion-label>
                                            <ion-button style="float: right;">
                                                mmmm
                                            </ion-button>
                                        </ion-item>
                                    </ion-list>
                                </ion-card-content>
                                <ion-card-content class="stretch_content_horizontally">
                                    <ion-button id="button_one" type="button" disabled>
                                        aaaa
                                    </ion-button>
                                    <ion-button id="button_two" type="button" disabled>
                                        bbbbb
                                    </ion-button>
                                </ion-card-content>
                            </ion-card>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>

                    <ion-row id="col_lower_half" style="width: 85%; background-color: #2b669a;">
                        <ion-col style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                            <ion-card id="card-owner-info">
                                <ion-card-header>
                                    <ion-card-title>
                                        Block #3
                                    </ion-card-title>
                                </ion-card-header>
                                <ion-card-content class="stretch_content_horizontally">
                                    <ion-card style="width: 50%;">
                                        <ion-card-content>
                                            <ion-item>
                                                <ion-label>
                                                    Variable #1: <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Some link</a>
                                                </ion-label>
                                            </ion-item>
                                            <ion-item>
                                                <ion-label>
                                                    Variable #2
                                                </ion-label>
                                            </ion-item>
                                        </ion-card-content>
                                        <ion-card-content class="stretch_content_horizontally">
                                            <ion-button id="button_one" disabled type="submit" onclick="">
                                                pppppppp
                                            </ion-button>
                                            <ion-button id="button_two" disabled type="submit">
                                                ccccccc
                                            </ion-button>
                                        </ion-card-content>
                                    </ion-card>
                                    <ion-card style="width: 50%;">
                                        <ion-card-content>
                                            <ion-item>
                                                <ion-textarea rows="5" readonly placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "></ion-textarea>
                                            </ion-item>
                                        </ion-card-content>
                                    </ion-card>
                                </ion-card-content>
                            </ion-card>
                            <ion-label>
                                <p class="ion-text-center copyright_notice_text">Copyright Notice.</p>
                                <br>
                            </ion-label>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-col>

                <ion-col id="grid_right_half" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; background-color: #1b6d85;" class="col_vertical_align">
                    <ion-card id="block_four" style="height: 80%; width: 85%; resize: vertical; ">
                        <ion-card-header>
                            <ion-card-title>
                                Block #4
                            </ion-card-title>
                        </ion-card-header>
                        <ion-card-content id="log" style="height: 90%; width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">
                            <div style="padding: 0 0 20px 0">
                                <ion-textarea id="log-txt" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow-wrap: anywhere;" auto-grow wrap="hard" readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</ion-textarea>
                            </div>
                        </ion-card-content>
                    </ion-card>
                    <ion-card id="block_five" style="width: 85%;">
                        <ion-card-content class="stretch_content_horizontally">
                            <ion-item style="width: 88%">
                                <ion-input id="log-input" minlength="1" maxlength="350" clear-input placeholder="Type your message..."></ion-input>
                            </ion-item>
                            <ion-button id="log-submit" type="button" >
                                Send
                            </ion-button>
                        </ion-card-content>
                    </ion-card>
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col></ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
</ion-app>

<script>
.stretch_content_horizontally {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.col_vertical_align {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center
}
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here's your answer.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Add this in between your <head></head> tags -->
```

PS : OBVIOUSLY, YOU NEED TO EDIT THIS TO YOUR LIKING!! IF YOU NEED EXPLANATION, SEARCH UP 'Meta, HTML.'!